# Chrome delays opening local site by IP address

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, lan

Sometimes I am trying to open LAN web server with Chrome by IP address and observing very long delay.

How to debug it?

What can cause it (except server side delay)?

Comment: Is the IP an internal one? (10.x or 192.168.x). Your router may be trying to find it externally before looking for it locally. Are you sure chrome is generating the delay?

Comment: Sure I am not sure :) I would like to find out this

Comment: @BrydonGibson sorry what you said is not possible. If IP address falls into netmask, network card is connecting directly to destination. Router can not interfere here.